# Force use of gcc while cplusplus is defined

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I'm in position where I have to use code that is only compiled if the __cplusplus flag is defined, what normally happens when compiling with g++.

The issue, I have to compile with gcc, and need some way to define __cplusplus without the library files using the __cplusplus defines.

So my question: Is it possible to use the __cplusplus flag only in NOT library files? Or is this simply impossible?

For anyone wondering why I ever want to do this, we are switching from a g++ compiler to the gcc compiler, and for backwards compatibility we (prefer) don't wan't to change all __cplusplus  defines towards something else.

If anyone could help me out/confirm it's not possible what I want would be awesome.

Note: all the code is c code, not c++. There used to be a single c++ file in the code making it necessary to use g++ instead the gcc compiler.  Everything is c code now.

Comment: The `__cplusplus` **macro** will be defined for C++ code. This is not used (and shall not be used) for C code. If you ahve compiled C code with C++ compiler, you did something fundamental wrong, as both are different languages with partly different semantics and requirements. Your question sound like an XY-problem. What do you actually want to accomplish?

Comment: @Olaf Compiling C code with a C++ compiler is not nearly as wrong as what the OP is trying now, which is compiling C++ code with a C compiler. The former is just a bad idea, the latter is pretty much guaranteed to fail.

Comment: @hvd: Compiling C++ code with a C compiler will eventually fail. So I presume it is C code which is compiled as C++, which is what I refer to. Anyway, OP should clarify.

Comment: My bad for not adding enough information.  All the code is c code, not c++ code.  There used to be some c++ code for a Windows build of this software.  For the Windows build the code was compiled using g++, mainly using c code with a single file of C++. The c++ code is rewritten to c but voor de Windows build al lot of   code is only compiled with the __cplusplus macro.  For this reason I want the cplusplus macro to be up, while using the gcc compiler  (which is absolutely save to use since Its only c code)

Comment: The code works either way, the whole point of doing this is to get rid of the g++ compiler for c code.  (this was given, not my idea, I'm trying to clean up). So to put it again: is it possible to make the cplusplus macro's stay just to not replace a lot of macro's for earlier explained reasons?

Comment: Why do you stick to __cplusplus? Just create a macro of your own. "for backwards compatibility we (prefer) don't wan't to change all __cplusplus defines towards something else" - all I read is "we intentionally want to make our lifes harder for no good reason".

Comment: I'm with @KarolyHorvath here. If *this* isn't an appropriate time for refactoring, I don't know what else would be ...

Comment: It's not that **I** want to keep using it. In my implementation I already replaced it so pleas don't get. me wrong. I was just wondering for an alternative. A simple "no this isnt possible " would have been enough.  these cplusplus macro's wil stay in the code anyway for some builds, all I wanted to know if it was possible to use it instead using #if defined(__cplusplus) || defined(anyOtherMacro).